# Bind query strings from Web API 2 to JSON Property in .NET 4.8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding, webapi

I have the following class and action on a Web API endpoint.  I would like the query string `sid` to bind to the property `SportId` like it does for JSON.NET serializing.  `SportId` works just fine as a querystring with the `FromUri`.  Is there a binder of some sort I can do this with using .NET 4.8.

```
public class AppApplicationRequest : AppRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sid")]
        public SportType? SportId { get; set; }

    }


public virtual async Task<AppApplicationResponse> Get([FromUri] AppApplicationRequest request)
{
    return await _appApplicationsService.GetApplication(request);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to create a custom model binder using IModelBinder?

Comment: I have no because I dont know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general guide on how to accomplish a custom model binder.

Here's a simple example of how you could create a custom model binder for your AppApplicationRequest class:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class AppApplicationRequestBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(AppApplicationRequest))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var queryString = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
        var appApplicationRequest = new AppApplicationRequest();

        if (queryString["sid"] != null)
        {
            if (Enum.TryParse(typeof(SportType), queryString["sid"], out object parsedSportType))
            {
                appApplicationRequest.SportId = (SportType)parsedSportType;
            }
        }

        // Add more fields if needed

        bindingContext.Model = appApplicationRequest;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Next, register your custom binder! This will be in something like `WebApiConfig.cs`

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // ... Other configurations

        config.BindParameter(typeof(AppApplicationRequest), new AppApplicationRequestBinder());
    }
}
```

Now you can annotate the action you want accomplish, like this:

```
public virtual async Task<AppApplicationResponse> Get([ModelBinder(typeof(AppApplicationRequestBinder))] AppApplicationRequest request)
{
    return await _appApplicationsService.GetApplication(request);
}
```

Again, this is generalized because you didn't put too much specific information in your question, but I hope this helps put you in the right direction. Let me know if you have follow up questions in the comments and I'll answer the best I can, good luck

Comment: This has to be generic.  I know how to do that, but it needs to bind just like the FromUri binding does.  It reads the query strings and automatically binds to the model names.  I want the same thing but I want it to bind to the Json.Net property names instead of the property names. You didn't once do anything with JSON.Net which is my issue.

Comment: I understand, I don't think I understood your question until now. I will update my answer to see if I can help.